# How to change words after match containing slash

Tags: bash, sed

Inside my file "input.txt" I have the following path written:

```
"/home/inputfiles/water_gen/5202_water.gen"
```

I want to change "5202" by specific numbers (probably using a for loop) and save them as different files.

I thought the easiest way was to use sed to find "water_gen/" as a match and then change the rest.

But is there an easier approach? I've been having problems because of the slash.

Comment: What was the problem? Escaping `/` or using a delimiter other than `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use `sed`. This can be nicely solved with `awk` as well.

You can just substitute the prefix of the basename part (filename) of the path. The snippets below will edit the file in-place:

```
NUM=0005
sed -Ei 's/(\/home\/inputfiles\/water_gen\/)[0-9]+(_water\.gen)/\1'"$NUM"'\2/' input.txt
cat input.txt
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0005_water.gen
```

You can also generalize the filename suffix, instead of hardcoding it, depending on your problem. For now I assume this is sufficient.

If you want to run this in a loop, do

```
for NUM in $(seq -f "%04g" 0 5); do
    sed -Ei 's/(\/home\/inputfiles\/water_gen\/)[0-9]+(_water\.gen)/\1'"$NUM"'\2/' input.txt;
    cat input.txt
done
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0000_water.gen
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0001_water.gen
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0002_water.gen
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0003_water.gen
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0004_water.gen
/home/inputfiles/water_gen/0005_water.gen
```

Comment: but the filename's path isn't "/home/inputfiles/water_gen/5202_water.gen", that path is just some text written inside the file I want to change called "input.txt". Perhaps I was not clear enough

Comment: Thanks! Either awk or sed are fine to use.

Comment: I added the full path, so this will not inadvertently change other lines as well.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel --dry sed -E 's/[0-9]+/{1}/' {2} \> {2.}{1}.txt ::: {1000..1005} ::: file.txt
```

This produces the command set to replace the first group of numbers in `file.txt` with `1000` to `1005` and write the results to `file1000.txt` to `file1005.txt`.

Once the command set has been verified, remove the `--dry` short for `--dry-run`  option and rerun.

N.B. The original file is not changed.

The substitution can be more specific, i.e.:

```
parallel sed -E \''s#(/home/inputfiles/water_gen/)5202(_water.gen)#\1{1}\2#'\' {2} \> {2.}{1}.txt ::: {1000..1005} ::: file.txt
```

N.B. The sed command quotes are quoted `\'` so that the back references are not mistaken for things in the shell.

Or, a little less specific:

```
parallel sed -E \''s#(/home/inputfiles/water_gen/)[0-9]+(_water.gen)#\1{1}\2#'\' {2} \> {2.}{1}.txt ::: {1000..1005} ::: file.txt
```

The replacement numbers may be in a file:

```
cat <<\! > replacementsFile
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
!
parallel sed -E \''s#(/home/inputfiles/water_gen/)5202(_water.gen)#\1{1}\2#'\' {2} \> {2.}{1}.txt :::: replacementsFile ::: file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If this part `5202` is known than change it directly

```
sed -i 's/5202/153/' input.txt
```

If not use regexp

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\+/153/' input.txt
```

Comment: the problem with the second one is that it is going to change every single number in my file. But thanks for your help!